# Magento - How to add multiple items to the cart programmatically?

Tags: magento, cart, product

I'm trying to add multiple simple products to the cart at the same time using a query string as below, however it only adds the last product to the cart instead of both:

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/checkout/cart/add?product=9916&qty=4&product=15749&qty=4
```

I have also tried this:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/checkout/cart/add?product[]=9916&qty[]=4&product[]=15749&qty[]=4
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Easy to use this extension [Magento 2 Add Multiple Products to Cart](https://www.magespark.com/magento-2-add-multiple-products-to-cart-extension.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Add Product To Cart With Querystring**

- Add simple product in shopping cart with no attribute.

  ```
  http://yourserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=PRODUCT_ID&qty=PRODUCT_QUANTITY
  ```

  Here PRODUCT_ID = 'Product Id',PRODUCT_QUANTITY = 'product quantity to purchase'.
- Add product into shopping cart with single custome option.

  ```
  http://yourserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=PRODUCT_ID&qty=PRODUCT_QUANTITY&super_attribute[OPTION_ID]=OPTION_VALUE
  ```

  Here OPTION_ID = 'Custom attribute option id',OPTION_VALUE = 'Custom attribute option value'.
- Add product into shopping cart with multipal custome option.

  ```
  http://yourserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=PRODUCT_ID&qty=PRODUCT_QUANTITY&super_attribute[OPTION_ID_1]=OPTION_VALUE_1&super_attribute[OPTION_ID_2]=OPTION_VALUE_2
  ```

  Here OPTION_ID_1 & OPTION_ID_1 = 'Custom attribute option ids',OPTION_VALUE_1 & OPTION_VALUE_2 = 'Custom attribute option values'.Here add more options in `super_attribute` array
- Add Extra products with mail product with only 1 quantity.

  ```
  http://yourserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=PRODUCT_ID&qty=PRODUCT_QUANTITY&related_product=PRODUCT_ID_1,PRODUCT_ID_2
  ```

  Here PRODUCT_ID_1 and PRODUCT_ID_2 is other products id. add more product by id using `,` separator. Example:- &related_product=1,2,3,4.

Default magento there is not setting for add related product quantity into cart.so if you want to add this code than open `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` find `public function addAction()`.

```
if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }
```

Replace with

```
$rel_qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_qty');
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $relatedproducts = explode(',', $related);
                $relatedqtys = explode(',',$rel_qty);
                $i = 0;
                foreach($relatedproducts as $relatedproduct)
                {
                    $cart->addProduct($relatedproduct, array('qty'=>$relatedqtys[$i]));
                $i++;
                }
            }
```

Now use query string for add related products with quantity.

```
http://yourserver.com/cart/add?product=PRODUCT_ID&qty=PRODUCT_QUANTITY&related_product=PRODUCT_ID_1,PRODUCT_ID_2&related_qty=PRODUCT_ID_1_QUANTITY,PRODUCT_ID_2_QUANTITY
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change any code, you can try to utilize *related* products functionality by adding **related_product** parameter to your request. So your url will look like this:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/checkout/cart/add?product=9916&qty=4&related_product=15749
```

If you want to add more products, just list them with comma separator: `related_product=1,2,3`
The only drawback from that is that you actually can't specify the qty for related products.
To see how it works - `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProductsByIds(array_of_ids)`

If qty for subsequent products is a mandatory for you, you'll need to create your own controller, or override the `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction` method.

Answer (score 1):

I found a cheeky way I found of getting around the quantity limitation of the related_products query string field noted above in other answers. If you just put the SAME ID MULTIPLE TIMES in the value of related_products, as many times as the quantity you need, then that will achieve the same effect as if there was an explicit qty field for each related product. So taking himansu's answer above and adapting it we get:
http://yourserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=PRODUCT_ID&qty=PRODUCT_QUANTITY&related_product=PRODUCT_ID_1,PRODUCT_ID_1,PRODUCT_ID_1,PRODUCT_ID_2,PRODUCT_ID_2

This will add to the cart PRODUCT_QUANTITY of PRODUCT_ID, 3 of PRODUCT_ID_1, and 2 of PRODUCT_ID_2.

So as long as you're happy doing a little work to generate the same ID multiple times this works a treat. And no custom code changes required on your magento server.